# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' in geolite2 function in python

Tags: python

I have a program that displays the country belongs to the Ip address.Its working fine in version python 2.7.The problem is when i try the same program in version python 3.5 ,it throws an error as mentioned below:

Code:

```
from geoip import geolite2

m = geolite2.lookup('17.0.0.1')
```

Error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How can i resolve the error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: '17.0.0.1' is a string. Your error message means the function is expecting bytes: b'17.0.0.1'.

Comment: str.encode(yourstring)

Comment: Hello BoarGules,when i tried that it displays the same error ..

>>> i=b'17.0.0.1'

>>> type(i)

<class 'bytes'>

>>> match = geolite2.lookup(i)

output:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 7):

The answer above was correct to install the right package for Python3. To force installation for Python3 use:

`python3 -m pip install python-geoip-python3`

However, to benefit from the full functionality of geoip you may also consider downloading additionally **geolite2** that also ships the IP database with it:

`python3 -m pip install python-geoip-geolite2`

To check if it works for you:

1. run python3 in interactive mode
2. run following:

```
>>> from geoip import geolite2
>>> geolite2.lookup('8.8.8.8')
```

You should get something like this

```
<IPInfo ip='8.8.8.8' country='US' continent='NA' subdivisions=frozenset({'CA'}) ...
```

Comment: I'm experiencing a weird situation, whenever I install python-geoip-python3 I need to uninstall it then reinstall it in order for it to work again. Any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the python 3 library:

`pip install python-geoip-python3`

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.

Comment: I am using Python-geoip-python3 and I still get this error

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the lib https://github.com/mitsuhiko/python-geoip will work in `Python 3.x`.

I looked at the source code in GitHub; it is 5 years without updates, and it still uses `Python 2.x` constructs (like `xrange()` in [this line `geoip.py#L255`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/python-geoip/blob/master/geoip.py#L255)) that will not work in `Python 3.x` (maybe you get lucky and your code doesn't call the parts of the code with old constructs, but I wouldn't hold my breath).

It looks like you will have to clone the repo and adapt it to `3.x` yourself or look for alternatives.